# Python - IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

My program is meant to generate a random password that's 5 characters long using the characters given below in the char variable. The issue is with the randint i believe and cannot figure out why.

```
from random import randint
print("1. 5 Letters")
enc = input("Please enter your desired option: ")
if enc == "1":
    chars = str()
    for i in range (1, 6+1):
        chars += str("\"~`<>.,?/:;}{[]+_=-)(*&^%$£@!±§qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890" [randint(1, 67)])
    print("Your password is: " + chars)
    print("\n")

    yon = input("Do you want a new password (yes or no): ")
    if yon == "yes":

        np = int(input("How many new passwords do you want: "))
        print("\n")
        count = 0
        for i in range(1, np+1):
            count += 1
            chars = str() 
            for i in range (1, 6 + 1):
                chars += "\"~`<>.,?/:;}{[]+_=-)(*&^%$£@!±§qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890" [randint(1, 67)]
            print("Your password is : " + str(chars) + "  This is password number: " + str(count) + "/" + str(np))
            print("\n")
    elif yon == "no":
        print("Goodbye.")
```

I get this error after getting to the part where my program generates the additional passwords.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rogerhylton/Desktop/Coding/Python/te.py", line 25, in <module>
    chars += "\"~`<>.,?/:;}{[]+_=-)(*&^%$£@!±§qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890" [randint(1, 67)]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> randint(1, 3)
2
>>> randint(1, 3)
3
>>> help(randint)
Help on method randint in module random:

randint(a, b) method of random.Random instance
    Return random integer in range [a, b], including both end points.
```

Since your string has length 67, the largest index it can take is 66, but you are sometimes trying to get the index 67, hence the `IndexError`.

Also, the first character is obtained by index 0:

```
>>> "abc"[0]
'a'
>>> "abc"[1]
'b'
>>> "abc"[2]
'c'
>>> "abc"[3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Therefore you should use `[randint(0, 66)]`.

Or better yet:

```
# Declare this variable once
possible_chars = "\"~`<>.,?/:;}{[]+_=-)(*&^%$£@!±§qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890"

# Use this line in both places instead of duplicating the string literal
char = possible_chars[randint(0, len(possible_chars) - 1)]
```

or use this function in both places:

```
def get_random_char():
    possible_chars = "\"~`<>.,?/:;}{[]+_=-)(*&^%$£@!±§qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890"
    return possible_chars[randint(0, len(possible_chars) - 1)]
```

and finally:

```
from random import choice

def get_random_char():
    possible_chars = "\"~`<>.,?/:;}{[]+_=-)(*&^%$£@!±§qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890"
    return choice(possible_chars)
```

Comment: OP *should* be using a dynamic value instead of a set integer, but you're not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There see 2 things in your code.

1. There is no need to explicitly tell `chars = str()`; you have declared this variable twice.
2. In Line 25: put `str()` outside the value of `chars` i.e.

   ```
   chars += str("\"~<>.,?/:;}{[]+_=-)(*&^%$£@!+§qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890" [randint(1, 67)])
   ```